# Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)

Tags: centos

I am trying to install (yum install git) but at the end it throws me an error that is:

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.12.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
            Requires: libcurl.so.3 () (64bit)
```

I want to install (`git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt`) but I can not continue after the error.

Then run (`yum list --showduplicates libcurl \ *`) to see what I have installed and this is what appears to me.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: mirror1.34sp.com
 * base: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: centos.datente.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centosmirror.netcup.net
Installed Packages
libcurl.x86_64                                                              7.19.7-37.el6_4                                                        @updates
Available Packages
libcurl.i686                                                                7.19.7-46.el6                                                          base    
libcurl.x86_64                                                              7.19.7-46.el6                                                          base    
libcurl-devel.i686                                                          7.19.7-46.el6                                                          base    
libcurl-devel.x86_64                                                        7.19.7-46.el6
```

My server is a:
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Linux server x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image: yum list --showduplicates libcurl \ *]

Can someone help me please? If I have to erase or delete it or be able to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to CentOS 6

First call

```
yum remove rpmforge-release*
```

Then

```
yum install git
```

Answer (score 1):

The package name git-1.7.12.4-1.el5.rf.x86_ indicates its trying to pull in a CentOS 5 dependency but you're on CentOS 6. Chances are when you installed the repoforge repo, you installed the CentOS 5 one instead of the CentOS 6 one. If you uninstall the CentOS 5 one and install the CentOS 6 one it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
# rpm -qa|grep el5

ffmpeg-0.6.5-1.el5.rf.i386

lame-3.99.5-1.el5.rf.i386

opencore-amr-0.1.2-1.el5.rf.i386

rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386

a52dec-0.7.4-8.el5.rf.i386

faac-1.26-1.el5.rf.i386

ffmpeg-libpostproc-0.6.5-1.el5.rf.i386

x264-0.0.0-0.4.20101111.el5.rf.i386

# rpm --erase rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386

# yum install git
```

Comment: OP has a problem between CentOS 6 and CentOS 5 dependencies.  The solution for CentOS 5 is not very useful for him.